# How to roll a log file when the file is inaccessible

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog, serilog-sinks-file

In a .net-core console app, I'm using **Serilog file sink** for logging. For configuration, I provide a file path (`F:\\log.json`) for file sink to write logs. Assume that the **specified file is read-only**, I expect Serilog file sink to write logs on a new file (e.g. `F:\\log_1.json`) but Serilog file sink actually give up on writing the log to file.

Here is my sample code. I simplified my code to demonstrate the issue.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File("F:\\\\log.json")
            .CreateLogger();

        logger.Information("Hello, stackoverflow :D");
    }
}
```

I also tried passing `shared: true` to the `File` extension method, but the behavior doesn't change.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: I'd like to add `serilog-sinks-file` tag, but I can't create a new tag because of my reputation. I appreciate if someone create this tag.